# Users with a gold tag badge should be able to add questions with no accepted or upvoted answers to the duplicate list for an already closed question

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, unanswered-questions, dupehammer

When anyone other than a moderator attempts to close a question as a duplicate, they can only select questions that have at least one answer that is upvoted or accepted. Even users with a gold badge in a relevant tag, who therefore have unilateral closing power, cannot do this.

However, users with a gold badge can *add* duplicate links once a question is already closed. Yet even then they cannot add a question that lacks an upvoted or accepted answer:

[image: Screenshot of attempt to add duplicate link]

If a question is already closed then what would be the problem with adding another question to the duplicate list? The question will remain closed regardless, so what is the point of disabling this behavior?

Granted, the extra benefit of being able to add such questions won't be that much, since by definition there will be no new positive-scoring answers that aren't already linked to the closed question. However, there may be answers without a positive score that might still be useful to have linked, or there may be interesting comments relating to the topic, so there could still be some benefit.

Additionally, one could argue that is beneficial to add more linked questions (even with no new content) just to show how often the same question has already been asked.

Can this feature be enabled?

Comment: If this would get implemented then there would need to be some check that is run before you can remove a question from the list. Otherwise we may end up with a situation where [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325921/why-can-i-bypass-the-duplicate-closure-prevention-system-on-some-questions-but-n) could be used to abuse the system.

Comment: You can leave a comment on one or both questions referring to the other, or upvote an answer on the potential duplicate.  Possibly the newer question turns out to be better, and the older one should be closed as a duplicate of the newer.  A duplicate question is used for a question that has already been asked and has an answer.  An unanswered (duplicate) question does not help the poster of the new question.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Upvoting won't help if the answer has a negative score, or if it's your own answer.

Comment: @1201Prog ... While an 'unanswered question duplicate' may not help the OP such closures are permitted on Meta: "[How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/282094)": "Unanswered duplicates: Generally, a question cannot be closed as a duplicate of a question with no upvoted or accepted answers, unless: 1: the site is a meta site, 2: ..." ***and*** "... if the same bug report or feature request has been filed in the past, but received no answers, it should be closed as a duplicate. ... vote to close a question as a duplicate of an unanswered one, ...".

Answer (score -3):

There is a potential downside to allowing this feature. If a user with a gold tag badge wants to close a question as a duplicate of a question with no upvoted or accepted answer a simple way around the barrier would be to close it as a duplicate of any random question (that does have an upvote or an accepted answer) and then simply add the intended question.

And if we think that there is no problem with a user doing that then we may as well remove the barrier altogether.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call that a problem - as long as at least one of the targets isn't unanswered, there's still an answer to point to in the notice. It's only a problem to *remove* answered questions from the notice, such that the *only* targets are unanswered.

Comment: And then again we are speaking of gold badge users, I hardly assume they will intentionally game the system....

Comment: -1 for the drawback "any random question" which is frankly irresponsible, and even more irresponsible is selecting a question with no answers to replace the "random question". Users with dupehammers who did anything similar would immediately get called out, and possibly attract moderator flags.